# Is it possible to use DWR if the DWR servlet is deployed in a different war?

Tags: java, ajax, dwr

I wanted to use DWR from web application A, but the DWR servlet is in web application B.

Is this possible? Is there any work-around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, totally you can do that.

When you include the generated javascript file to be used in application A, you need to specify the B application path (where the dwr servlet is deployed) as follows:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='[application B path]/dwr/interface/[javascript class name].js'></script>
```

`[application B path]` would be something like http://my-domain.com/AppB

`[javascript class name]` would be as delcared in **dwr.xml** on application B

```
<create creator="new" javascript="[javascript class name]">
    <param name="class" value="com.my-domain.Class"/>
</create>
```

and you can use any core javascript classes as follows:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='[application B path]/dwr/engine.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='[application B path]/dwr/util.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch static content from a dwr servlet in another web app, via requests on the client side.

However, you won't have access to services/business objects/session/request/state from one application to another - without custom modifications.